# Принять данные пост запроса TcpClient

Tags: c#, tcplistener

Собственно нужно принять данные которые отправили нам в пост запросе, есть код для гет запроса, он работать нормально, по сколько любой гет запрос заканчивается \r\n\r\n а вот пост запрос обрезает данные

```
// Объявим строку, в которой будет хранится запрос клиента
string Request = "";
// Буфер для хранения принятых от клиента данных
byte[] Buffer = new byte[1024];
// Переменная для хранения количества байт, принятых от клиента
int Count;
// Читаем из потока клиента до тех пор, пока от него поступают данные
while ((Count = Client.GetStream().Read(Buffer,  0, Buffer.Length)) >  0)
{
    // Преобразуем эти данные в строку и добавим ее к переменной Request
    Request += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer,  0, Count);
    // Запрос должен обрываться последовательностью \r\n\r\n
    // Либо обрываем прием данных сами, если длина строки Request превышает 4 килобайта
    // Нам не нужно получать данные из POST-запроса (и т. п.), а обычный запрос
    // по идее не должен быть больше 4 килобайт
    if (Request.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n") >=  0 || Request.Length > 4096)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему TcpClient?  
Принимает разве не Server?  
Почему TCP, когда должен быть HTTP?

Comment: Нужно просто прочитать данные с потока и всё

Comment: А почему не [`HttpListener`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2)? Вы делаете вручную то, что по идее уже сделано за вас.

Comment: у меня TcpListener